# BigCommerce outgoing webhook when an order is placed

Tags: bigcommerce

I am creating a custom app on the BigCommerce platform. I am wondering if it is possible to send a webhook request going from BigCommerce when an order has been placed. Currently I can only see that it is sending an email notification, but I would like to send a webhook request to a url instead.

For example, so that a post request is sent from BigCommerce to a certain URL everytime an order has been placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Webhooks API to create a new webhook that fires on a new order:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/webhooks/webhooks/createwebhooks

That includes an endpoint you can specify to listen to events - that payload contains the order id of the new order.

More info here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/webhooks/overview

And all events here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/webhooks/events